# Sentry database growing large and not reducing after running vaccum

Tags: postgresql, sentry

I have strnage issue as one of the tables for the sentry database is growing large. It increaesed 40GB. There are other tables also increased the size but after running the VACCUM FULL these tables size got reduced.

But only for the table sentry_eventtag the size is not reducing after running the command. When I start running the vaccum it start reducing as it will show the freed disk space but after finishing the command the disk space usage will come back to the normal

Is there anyone have faced this issue? Is there anyway to resolve this issue?

Comment: "When I start running the vaccum it start reducing as it will show the freed disk space"  This does not sound like PostgreSQL's VACUUM FULL at all.  Where does it show the freed disk space?  What does it look like?  With real PostgreSQL, you can use OS tools to watch free space shrink, not grow, until the very end when it suddenly snaps back.

Comment: While vaccum was run the df shows the disk space getting  reduced but after finishing the command the df will be same as before running vaccum.

I have run the vaccum on other sentry tables and its size drastically reduced. When I run on nodestore table it reduced from 19 gb to 1.5gb

Comment: VACUUM FULL can consolidate the free space and then return it to the OS.  But if there is no free space, nothing can be returned.   You can't remove bloat if there is none there in the first place.  It sounds like this table is just not bloated, but is really using that large amount of space for live data.  While your other tables really were bloated, so they do get shrunk.